# How to name different data display types?

Tags: gui-design, terminology, dynamic-ui

I'm working on this specific system where we're allowing users to save search data for future re-use based on 3 criteria:

1. **Save based on searched term** (eg, if I searched for "Foo", the user will save "Foo" as a saved search)
2. **Save based on search template** (here, users will be able to create a faceted search and then save custom views by choosing columns and sorting order. Then they can do any search, but results will be displayed using the custom view)
3. **Save based on Most Used Terms** (here the system will automatically save repetitive search terms)

What I need is to name each **save** button. I have problem finding a proper naming convention for the second scenario. I think **Save Template** is confusing for a search pattern, but I can't really find anything better. While I understand I need to test, I really have no other options to test against. Same goes for titles for these results. I have "Search Results Using Foobar Template" but not sure if it's OK

Just in case, these options are not persistent (obviously), but they show up on request by user interaction. For example: User does the sorting and filtering for a custom view and then the system offers the user the ability to save this filtering and/or sorting as a custom view or template.

The reasoning behind this is that there are millions of DB rows and close to 100 columns, so very few people will need to see all 100 columns at once, thus they will filter, sort and re-use custom views.

In short: **how can I name this search pattern? Is there anything similar you can show as example?**

Answer (score 1):

I think terminology is always tricky because the ideal scenario is to develop a vocabulary that aligns with everything else in the system rather than looking at a specific page or view.

However, just based on your brief description, you might want to consider some of these options:

- Save based on searched term: **Save term/keyword**
- Save based on search template: **Save criteria/view**
- Save based on Most Used Terms: **Save repeated terms/keywords**

I don't know of many examples (if at all) but I am curious about this and hopefully some others have come across them before.